# Модули es2015 и npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Объясните мне пожалуйста, как сохранить совместимость с модулями common.js?
Я написал модуль в синтаксисе `es2015`, в нём:

`export default data => {}`

Бэйбелем транспилировал и опубликовал в npm. Если работать с модулем в синтаксисе es2015, то он импортится:

`import name from 'name'`

А если common.js, то подлючается он только так:

`const name = require('name').default`

Как сделать, чтобы он подключался при common.js без `.default`